# Discrete features are less important

Tags: random-forest, importance

I am trying to train a random forest classifier. As predictors, I keep both discrete features and continuous features (the discrete ones including booleans, counters, etc., and the continuous contains floats).

Training the model both in `R` and in Python's `scikit.learn`, I get that the discrete features are always less important (using the importance feature of the model). I wonder if that's a characteristic of my data or perhaps there's some innate characteristic of discrete features.

I am not even sure it makes sense to mix discrete and continuous features in the same predictors matrix.

Some numbers: a current test with about 30 features (not much, it'll grow larger) yields mean importance 0.035; the continuous features importances range from 0.037 to 0.06 (mean > 0.04) and the discrete features importances range from 0.005 to 0.03 (mean < 0.02).

To sum, I have two questions:

1. is there something "inherent" in discrete features that makes them "less important" (according to the algorithm for importance calculation)
2. does it make sense to mix the feature types?